# Possible to tag a section in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a uitableview with cells whose behavior depends on what:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    do x;
   }else{
    do y;
  }   
}
```

It kind of works when you are dealing with a single table, but when you try to add sections, or subclass things, this type of "magic numbers" break very easily.

My question is, is it possible to "tag" the section? so instead of doing section==1, we will do:

```
indexPath.section.tag=="user_stats" {load x}
indexPath.section.tag=="answers" {show answers}
indexPath.section.tag=="page" {show pagination}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, just set up an enum somewhere.

```
enum {  kSectionUserStats = 0,
        kSectionAnswers,
        kSectionPage };
```

Then:

```
if(indexPath.section == kSectionPage)
{
    // do x
} else if(indexPath.section == kSectionAnswers)
{
    // do y
}
// etc.
```

This also lets you reorder your sections really easily just by changing their ordering in the enum.

Answer (score -1):

If you are displaying section headers with titles, then the titles themselves can become your tags.

```
if([self titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section] == @"MySection1")
{
     //do something
}
else
{
     //do something else
}
```

Comment: Wasn't there something about string comparision in Objective-C? `[string1 isEqualToString:string2]`